# Onmouseout event in javascript trigger

Tags: javascript, html

It seems that the onmouseout event in the .izberiLokacija class is being triggered by the onmouseout event in `<li>`. Is this the way Javascript works or am I doing anything wrong. If that is the case please suggest a possible solution to activate onmouseout event in the .izberiLokacija class only when leaving the div itself...

```
<div class="izberiLokacija" onmouseout="alert('asd');toggleDivZaMalaMapa(2);">
          <ul>
                    <li onmouseover="toggleDivZaMalaMapa(1);">li1</li>
                    <li onmouseover="toggleDivZaMalaMapa(1);" style="border-top: solid 2px #00699B"> li2 </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way JavaScript works. Either put a handler on each `<li>` to prevent bubbling (with `event.stopPropagation()` or by returning `false`), or test whether `event.target` is what you want it to be in your `.izberiLokacija` handler. Read more on event bubbling, that should clear up the confusion.

Another way is to replace `onmouseout`/`onmouseover` with `onmouseleave`/`onmouseenter`. They're almost the same event, but the latter pair does not bubble.

Off-topic: You will be much happier if you move from `alert` to `console.log`; also, inline JavaScript is hard to work with; consider separating your JS and HTML.

Comment: and `onmouseleave/onmouseenter` are not standard for all browsers, just works in IE, if you are not talking about jQuery mouse events.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I do use separete .js file...  
edit:
Now I get what you meant after reading the second comment, good to know...

Comment: @ocanal: Actually, currently it's Firefox, Opera and IE. Doesn't work on Webkit. But yeah, I guess one should use a library when messing with enter/leave.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you hover over an element... the "hover" event will fire.  Events will also bubble up the DOM tree and fire for each of it's parents... all the way to the body tag.

Please DO NOT assign events inline... it makes for hard to maintain code and bloated non-semantic markup.

Instead, try this (using jQuery... because everybody uses jQuery, right?)

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/fab8Z/